# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have a problem I need to convert a decimal number to
hexadecimal. So far I get more of the problem is I need to change the result to put \ x for example if the conversion gives "0x63dd" I need it to be "\ x63 \ xdd" but I can't put the \ x because this is giving the error

> ```
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes 
>     in position 0-1: truncated \ xXX escape
> ```

```
Decimal = 25565   
Hexa = hex(Decimal).replace("0x","")
N1 = Hexa[:2]
N2 = Hexa[2:]
print("\x"+N1)
print("\x"+N2)
```

Comment: Also, in whatever language, please show exactly what you did. Copy the command and error message from your terminal into the question.

Comment: Welcome in Stack Overflow! Please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/356878), and then possibly edit your question, explaining *why you need such a conversion.*

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact, that  `\x` has a special meaning. Namely for encoding stuff. If you want to prepend the litherals `backslash and x` to a string you need to do `"\\x" + N1`. (The first backslas escapes the secon one.)

So your code would become the following

```
Decimal = 25565   
Hexa = hex(Decimal).replace("0x","")
N1 = Hexa[:2]
N2 = Hexa[2:]
print("\\x"+N1)
print("\\x"+N2)
```

and returns

```
\x63
\xdd
```

Comment: I understand this already helps a lot if it is not asking for a lot as I would pass this to bytes without getting b '\\x63'?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to convert the strings back to byte-objects? Then use `bytes.fromhex(N1.replace("\\x",""))` which should result in `b'\xdd'`.

Comment: If this answer helped you pleas [upvote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it to show others that it worked. Have a nice day!

Comment: Yes, that was the case with "\ xdd" it worked but when trying "\ x63" it just turns 'c'

Comment: Yes, this is correkt. Because `0x63` can be represented as an ASCII-Charakter. But `0xdd` cannot so its hex-representation is used as a fallback. But it is still the right data under the hood.

Comment: There is no way to convert this keeping the '\ x63'?

Comment: No. Then you will need to keep the string-format. This is intrinsic to the byte-type. But the byte-type is not ment for printing. (Also remember to accept the answer.) :D

Comment: Every time I try to answer it he says I need 15 reputation.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak — Literal answers to bad questions can be dangerous. Please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/356878).

Comment: Ok. I see what I did there. Thank you for telling me! I will read carefully.

Comment: @vicnor Python integers have a `.to_bytes` method, e.g. `(25565).to_bytes(2,'big')` will generate a 2-byte big-endian value.

Comment: printing it will generate the desired string, but right now my strings look like "\\x64" or whatever... and I want to .join() a list of these, but when I print the new string it outputs "\\x64\\x73", etc etc.